# why zipping the result of a function and iterable does not work?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-itertools, process-pool

So I had the following code which works fine:

```
from  concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor 
import itertools

def grid_search_helper(vec_input):
    v1 = vec_input[0]
    v2 = vec_input[1]
    v3 = vec_input[2]
    d = {'v1' : v1, 'v2' : v2, 'v3' : v3}
    return(d)

idx = range(0,10)
cutoff = np.ndarray.tolist(np.arange(0.6,0.95,0.05))
opt = [2]

iters = itertools.product(idx, cutoff, opt)

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 11) as executor:
        for  res in executor.map(grid_search_helper,iters):
            print(res)
```

Then I tried zip() to print the iterable that ProcessPoolExecuter is working on, however nothing is printed when I run the following code:

```
from  concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor 
import itertools

def grid_search_helper(vec_input):
    v1 = vec_input[0]
    v2 = vec_input[1]
    v3 = vec_input[2]
    d = {'v1' : v1, 'v2' : v2, 'v3' : v3}
    return(d)

idx = range(0,10)
cutoff = np.ndarray.tolist(np.arange(0.6,0.95,0.05))
opt = [2]

iters = itertools.product(idx, cutoff, opt)

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 11) as executor:
        for  res, itr in zip(executor.map(grid_search_helper,iters), iters):
            print(res, itr)
```

I cannot figure out why. Can anybody help?

Comment: You can't iterate over `iters` (i.e. `itertools.product()`) twice. Either turn the iterator into a list, or re-create the iterator after `executor.map(grid_search_helper,iters)`.

Comment: You can duplicate your iterator with `itertools.tee`: `iter_a, iter_b = tee(iters)`.

Comment: @Daniel: Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the fact that you're zipping a function and an iterator.

The problem is you're using the same iterator twice:

```
#                                                      v       v
for res, itr in zip(executor.map(grid_search_helper, iters), iters):
    ...
```

The first time it's passed to `map`, it is consumed. By the time it is passed to `zip` again, it's already empty, so `zip` returns an empty generator, and there is nothing to iterate over.

Use `itertools.tee` to create two copies of the same iterator.

```
it1, it2 = itertools.tee(itertools.product(idx, cutoff, opt))

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 11) as executor:
    for  res, itr in zip(executor.map(grid_search_helper,it1), it2):
        print(res, itr)
```

Answer (score 1):

When it tries to execute `zip(..., iters)` the previously populated `iters` is already empty because `executor.map(grid_search_helper, iters)` has consumed all of its items.

So you're actually passing an empty iterator to `zip()`.